# Can't upgrade to Angular 1.3.8 with Bower on Rails 4

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, bower

I'm using Bower in my Vendor folder to keep track of libraries. In my bower.json file I have the following lines

```
{
  "name": "dsl-generated dependencies",
  "dependencies": {
     "angular": "1.3.4",
     "angular-foundation": "latest",
     "angular-ui-utils": "latest",
     "angular-ui-router": "latest",
     "angular-filter": "0.5.1",
     "angular-float-thead": "latest",
     "ngstorage": "latest",
     "ng-file-upload": "2.0.5",
     "oauth-ng": "0.3.5",
     "restangular": "latest",
    "angular-spinkit": "latest"
  }
}
```

When I change it to `"angular": "1.3.8"` and run `rake bower:update` I see the following:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#~1.2.26 which resolved to 1.2.28 and is required by oauth-ng#0.3.5 
    2) angular#* which resolved to 1.3.4 and is required by angular-filter#0.5.1, angular-spinkit#0.3.3, restangular#1.4.0 
    3) angular#1.3.4 which resolved to 1.3.4 and is required by dsl-generated dependencies 
    4) angular#>=1.0.8 which resolved to 1.3.4 and is required by ngstorage#0.3.0 
    5) angular#>=1 which resolved to 1.3.4 and is required by angular-foundation#0.5.1 
    6) angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to 1.3.4 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.13 
    7) angular#>= 1.0.2 which resolved to 1.3.4 and is required by angular-ui-utils#0.2.2Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer::
```

Anyone know why? Why is it not letting me upgrade to the correct version? Is it because it's locked somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Did you change the version of angular in your dependencies?

Comment: @drorb I thought that the bower.json file worked like the gemfile? Just change the version number there, do a ```rake bower:update``` and it will change the versions for you? Are you saying that there some other file I needed to change?

Comment: no it should be enough. Got confused by the bower.json with the 1.3.4 dependency

Comment: can you publish your full bower.json?

Comment: @drorb Please see updated bower.json. Thanks.